# Does a NSObject in an NSarray have knowledge about its position in the array?

Tags: nsarray, nsobject

I have an NSArray of objects displayed in a UITableView.
The user can tap a cell, and the item in current row is displayed in a new view by

```
MYItem *selectedItem = [myItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[itemViewController setMyItem:selectedItem];
```

[self navigationController] pushViewController:itemViewController
                                           animated:YES];

This works fine. But from here,the new view, I want to add a button that takes the user to the next item in the array

```
-(IBAction)nextItem:(id)sender
{
// I imagine that this have to contain something like 
  MyItem *selectedItem =[myItems objectAtCurrentIndex+1];
...
...

}
```

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as objectAtCurrentIndex. Do I have to run a loop to identify the current indexnumber? or is there another way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object doesn't know his position out of the box.
A loop would be one solution. You could add an int to the object which represents the position, but you have to manage at yourself